# Need help with javascript regarding radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

I want to disable the radiobutton the second time it is clicked..I want to put some code in the head..that when a radiobutton is clicked the second time,, it isnt marked anymore..

I want to check and uncheck the radiobutton with each click.

Note: I generate 20 radiobuttons dynamically

Take into account that it is a Radiobutton that is run on the server:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx
```

UPDATE: This is the only event that the RadioButton (asp WebControl run at="server") has:

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rad = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (rad.Checked)
    {

        rad.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

I can uncheck it after each post back..but unless a post back doesnt happen, i cant select and deselect it.. Thats the problem!! :(

Comment: Should the second click still select the radio button but disable at the same time? Should you still be able to click on other radio buttons after that? Or when you say "it isn't marked anymore" do you mean you want to unselect it on second click? Note: disabled form elements don't get submitted.

Comment: Do you want to actually disable it (so it can't be selected, and its value won't be passed back with the form), remove the selection of that radio button, or both?

Comment: Unless you automatically select another radio button upon user deselection you should be using `CheckBox` instead.

Comment: I want to be able to select and deselect it with a single click..i Dont want to use Checkbox..

Comment: have  you tried  anything then please post the code here

Comment: I suggest you update your question. If I understand you correctly you don't want to disable it at all, you want to deselect it. So clicking a radio button that is not currently selected will change the current selection to that radio button (standard behaviour), but clicking the currently selected one will deselect it leaving none selected (non-standard)?

Comment: Yeah..i updated my question.. It is an asp.net control and not an html control..take that into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i get you right then
    all u need is a flag attribute of how many times u have clicked on the radio button and each time u click the radio the attribute increased by 1 and check the attribute every click if its 2nd time then disable the radiobutton

so you need to generate ur radiobuttons like this

```
<input type='radio' onclick='radioClick(this);' how_many_clicked='0' id='whatever id u need' name='whatever name u need' />
```

and create ur function in the head like the following

```
   function radioClick(e) {

    var flag = e.getAttribute('how_many_clicked');
    var times = Number(flag);
    times += 1;
    e.setAttribute('how_many_clicked', times.toString())
    if (times > 1) {
        e.checked = false;
        e.setAttribute('how_many_clicked', "0");
    }
    else {
        e.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The radioButton hasnt got the event click..look at the updated question.. The events are listed in the link button... hmmm.. i dont do it in the conventional way.. and the buttons are also programmatically generated..e.g. RadioButton rb=new RadioButton().. i have no tags of radiobuttons

Comment: aha ok sorry for miss understanding 
i meant not adding it as tags i mean u with ur code add the onclick event and the additional attribute 
i will look at the q again and see to it thanx

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah i understand u now u add ur radio button in the server side

Comment: look at the events in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx  Do you see any "onClick" "Click" events?!?!? I dont!

Comment: well then add the function i gave u in the head of the page and add the onclick as an attribute in the server code and also the attribute

Comment: there is an onclick on the client side renderd radiobutton

Comment: the radiobutton u add is a server but in  the truth its an input type radio so keep up with me

Comment: so when u create ur object the radiobutton object in the server side code just add 
rbtn.Attributes["onclick"]="radioClicked(this)";

Comment: and the attribute i told u about to 
rbtn.Attributes["how_many_clicked"]="0";

Comment: I am trying to scan through its attributes and methods to see if it has something that changes the radiobutton state with each click.. An alternative way i could do it is through setting Autopostback=true.. but i dont want to make a post back..it would ruin the interface

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1173/discussion-between-marwan-and-dmitry-makovetskiyd)

Comment: Dmitry i updated my answer so please check it and feed me back :) is it helping

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep with the standard use of RadioButtons, by saying this - use **CheckBoxes** instead, and clear all checkboxes if a different one is clicked...so when a checkbox is clicked the second time the standard uncheck will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Id create an empty array. For every radiobutton you create, add its ID to the array as the key and set its value to 0. This will be the count for the specific button. Whenever a radiobutton is clicked, check the buttons ID against the array, if its less than 2, increment it. If not, disable the current button.

EDIT : didn't realize you were checking if it was already checked, thoguht it was the number of times checked.

$("#id").is(":checked")

Should suffice

Another note ...if all you're doing is disabling an element from being accessed by the user, you should handle this event on the client side. You'll be using unnecessary server callback for functionality easily achievable via javascript. Use jquery click event handlers which can be generic enough for you not to have to use identifiers, making the job that much easier.

Cheers

Comment: Isnt there a simple code.... onclick="checkIFchecked()" The problem is that i have one onclick event...as it is an asp.net control and i dont know if i can add another onclick event on the clients site

Comment: wait, why are you downvoted, this is exactly what I would have done!